# Correct syntax for Angular async pipe with as keyword

Tags: angular

The following structural directive will subscribe to the named observable and assign the locally scoped variable `srl` to the value.   The content only gets rendered when the result is truthy.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="searchResultLength$ | async as srl">
    (search results goes here)
</ng-container>
```

But what is the syntax if I want to have some other type of logical operator?   What I want to do is:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(searchResultLength$ | async as srl) > 2">
   (search results IF there are more than 2 goes here)
</ng-container>
```

Which looks to me like it should the correct syntax but is rejected by the compiler.  I can't find the document for how the `as` keyword is parsed.   Can someone clue me in what the correct syntax should be?

Also, a link to the relevant documentation would help.  Doing searches for the `as` keyword is as futile as it gets.

Comment: Perhaps `(searchResultLength$ | async as srl).length > 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is, in fact, not the correct syntax. The correct syntax for `ngIf` is

```html
<div *ngIf="condition as value">{{value}}</div>
```

The `as` syntax can only be used after the entire `ngIf` condition and stores the value that the condition evaluates to.

Here is an alternative.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="searchResultLength$ | async as srl">
  <ng-container *ngIf="srl > 2">
    (search results IF there are more than 2 goes here)
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I had thought of that but was hoping to have only a single *ngIf evaluation.  I'll mark this as the answer if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution (not really practical but working :)) using `*ngFor` and `slice` pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let srl of [length$ | async] | slice : (length$ | async) <= 2"> 
  (search results IF there are more than 2 goes here)
  <br>
  searchResultLength$ = {{ srl }}
</ng-container>
```

in order not to subscribe twice to `length$`, use it with piped `shareReplay()` operator. I also added `tap` with `console.log` to verify that we are subscribing only once although using `async` pipe twice:

```
length$ = new BehaviorSubject(3).pipe(tap(console.log), shareReplay());
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7pkcnr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts